# dependent packages not loading in R on Debian

Tags: r, package

I'm having trouble loading the `sde` package on a clean Debian install running R 2.11.1. I've seen this behavior with some other packages, however, so I don't think it's specific to only this one package. Here's an example of the conundrum:

```
>install.packages("sde", lib.loc=libPath)
```

... installs sde, and the packages it's dependent on: zoo, fda

```
> library(sde,  lib=libPath)
Loading required package: fda
Error: package 'fda' could not be loaded
In addition: Warning message:
In library(pkg, character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE, lib.loc = lib.loc) :
  there is no package called 'fda'
```

ok, that's odd. I saw fda being installed. So I manually load the dependencies:

```
> library(zoo,  lib=libPath)
> library(fda,  lib=libPath)
Loading required package: splines
```

ok, that worked. Now let's try sde:

```
> library(sde,  lib=libPath)
To check the errata corrige of the book, type vignette("sde.errata")
```

WTF? it loaded fine?!?

So why can I manually load the packages but R is not picking them up automagically?

Adding to my confusion, I discovered during debugging that if I don't use the `lib=libPath` then everything works just fine. So it looks like the use of a custom path for packages is screwing this all up... but why?

Comment: What happens if you load zoo before sde as fda seems to need it?

Comment: hmm. is `lib` passed along to the dependency-loading stage properly ... ?

Comment: if I do it from within R things don't change. I still have to manually install fde. However if I apt-get install it, things work.

Comment: Ben, I'm wondering about that.

Comment: What is `libPath` and `.libPaths()`? Are fda and zoo in `libPath`?

Comment: Where are you setting the libpath, and why do you diverge from the good standard once suggested by Kurt and Fritz? ;-)   Just say no to packages below $HOME.

Comment: @dirk, I diverge because I'm doing many many naughty naughty things. But I'm doing them in parallel so it's OK.

Comment: oh shit, @joshua you just solved my problem. The solution is to set `.libPaths(libPath)` instead of manually passing it to each install.packages() or library() call.

Comment: Then just don't ask us to clean your parallel messes for you :)

Comment: And then do it in `~/.Rprofile`, or set libPaths via `~/.Renviron`, but importantly *set it once and for all* -- see `help(Startup)`. And to be perfectly petty, I also suggested that answer when asking you about libpath settings.

Comment: @dirk, I really can't do that for this application. I do that on my desktop tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confirmed my suspicions in the comments.  You need to do one of two things:

```
.libPaths(libPath)
```

or

```
library(sde,  lib=c(libPath,.libPaths()))
```

I prefer the first method because the second requires you do that for all calls to `library`.